# Edittext turns out to be black in color when I use special symbols like @

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a little problem with my edittext fields, when you type in it, the whole field turns black when I type @ . - or any other symble.

```
<TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableEmail"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="40dp" 
             android:background="@drawable/cell_shape">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
               android:layout_width="45dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:ems="10"
               android:gravity="top"
               android:text="@string/email"
               android:textColor="#000000" /> 

                  <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/inputEmail"
                      android:layout_width="370dp"
                      android:layout_height="35dp"
                       android:background="@drawable/edit"
                      android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:ems="10"
                      android:inputType="text" >                   
            </EditText>
</TableRow>
```

I did try to chage the input type to textEmail, but it is the same.

My cell_shape looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape= "rectangle"  >
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

any ides?

edit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >


<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

Comment: what is the content of @drawable/edit?

Comment: just a white feild, to remove the ugly edit design

Comment: but it helps when I remove it , hmmm